# Merge two integer lists in Pascal

Tags: beginner, mergesort, pascal

The purpose of the code is to merge two ordered lists (list 1 : 5 integers, list 2 : 8 integers) into another third ordered list, whilst maintaining their order, while entries that appear in more than one list also appear multiple times in the result.

Example:

An input of List1 (Feld1): 3 6 7 9 10, merged with an input of List2(Feld2): 2 7 11 12 15 17 20 21 would result into a third list(Ergebnisfeld) of:
2 3 6 7 7 9 10 11 12 15 17 20 21.

This code works well on my computer, but since I am pretty new to this, I would like to ask, if this is:

1. The most efficient way to do this (e.g. is the combination of a while and a repeat/until loop the best code for this, or is a for loop better)
2. If there are any problems with the code, which I am too inexperienced to see, but which might cause me problems later

```
 program merge (input, output);
    { Reads two ordered lists of integers keyed in by the user, and merges 
them into a third ordered list, without checking their order. 
    if the input is not sorted, the result will be undefined.}

const
  FELDLAENGE1 = 5;
  FELDLAENGE2 = 8;
  ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE = 13; { FELDLAENGE1 + FELDLAENGE2}

type
  tFeld1 = array [1..FELDLAENGE1] of integer;
  tFeld2 = array [1..FELDLAENGE2] of integer;
  tErgebnisFeld = array [ 1..ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE] of integer;

var
  Feld1 : tFeld1;
  Feld2 : tFeld2;
  ErgebnisFeld : tErgebnisFeld;
  i : integer;
  j : integer;
  k : integer;
begin
  { read ordered lists (Felder) }
  writeln (' Please key in', FELDLAENGE1:2, ' values in ascending order for 
the first list. ');
  for i := 1 to FELDLAENGE1 do
      readln (Feld1[i]);
  writeln (' Please key in', FELDLAENGE2:2, ' values in ascending order for 
the second list. ');
  for j := 1 to FELDLAENGE2 do
      readln (Feld2[j]);
  { Merge Feld1 and Feld2 into ErgebnisFeld}
  i :=1;
  j :=1;
  k := 1;

  while (i <= FELDLAENGE1) and (j <= FELDLAENGE2) do
        if Feld1[i] <= Feld2[j] then
           begin
           ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
           i := i+1;
           k := k+1
          end
        else
        begin
          ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
          j := j +1;
          k := k +1
        end;
  { add remaining values to ErgebnisFeld}
  if i > FELDLAENGE1 then
     repeat
           ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
           j := j + 1;
           k := k + 1
     until k = ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE+1
  else
      repeat
            ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
            i := i + 1;
            k := k + 1
      until k = ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE+1;


  writeln ('The merged list is: ');
  for k := 1 to ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE do
      write (ErgebnisFeld[k], ' ');
  writeln;
  readln;

end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you might separate the input/output part from processing data by enclosing the merging routine in a separate `procedure`. Then the merging procedure can be reused in many places of your program. And if you move it to a separate unit you'll be able to reuse it in other programs, too, if necessary.

```
 program merge (input, output);
    { Reads two ordered lists of integers keyed in by the user, and merges 
    them into a third ordered list, without checking their order. 
    If the input is not sorted, the result will be undefined.}

const
  FELDLAENGE1 = 5;
  FELDLAENGE2 = 8;
  ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE = 13; { FELDLAENGE1 + FELDLAENGE2}

type
  tFeld1 = array [1..FELDLAENGE1] of integer;
  tFeld2 = array [1..FELDLAENGE2] of integer;
  tErgebnisFeld = array [ 1..ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE] of integer;

procedure mergeTwoArrays( var Feld1 : tFeld1; var Feld2 : tFeld2;
                          var ErgebnisFeld : tErgebnisFeld)
    var
        i : integer;
        j : integer;
        k : integer;
    begin
        i := 1;
        j := 1;
        k := 1;

        while (i <= FELDLAENGE1) and (j <= FELDLAENGE2) do
            if Feld1[i] <= Feld2[j] then
              begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
                i := i + 1;
                k := k + 1
              end
            else
              begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
                j := j + 1;
                k := k + 1
              end;
        { add remaining values to ErgebnisFeld}
        if i > FELDLAENGE1 then
            repeat
               ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
               j := j + 1;
               k := k + 1
            until k = ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE+1
        else
            repeat
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
                i := i + 1;
                k := k + 1
            until k = ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE+1;
    end;

var
  Feld1 : tFeld1;
  Feld2 : tFeld2;
  ErgebnisFeld : tErgebnisFeld;
  i : integer;
  j : integer;
begin
  { read ordered lists (Felder) }
  writeln (' Please key in', FELDLAENGE1:2, ' values in ascending order for the first list. ');
  for i := 1 to FELDLAENGE1 do
      readln (Feld1[i]);
  writeln (' Please key in', FELDLAENGE2:2, ' values in ascending order for the second list. ');
  for j := 1 to FELDLAENGE2 do
      readln (Feld2[j]);

  { Merge Feld1 and Feld2 into ErgebnisFeld}
  mergeTwoArrays( Feld1, Feld2, ErgebnisFeld);

  { output results from ErgebnisFeld}
  writeln ('The merged list is: ');
  for k := 1 to ERGEBNISFELDLAENGE do
      write (ErgebnisFeld[k], ' ');
  writeln;
  readln;

end.
```

Another change I would make is simplifying the code to append input lists' tails in the final part of merge – you can do that with two separate `while` loops, similar to the main merging loop. Exactly one of them will do the actual work, and the cost of *not* entering the other one equals the cost of the conditional (if-then-else) in your version.

```
      { add remaining values from Feld1 to ErgebnisFeld}
      while i <= FELDLAENGE1 do
          begin
              ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
              i := i + 1;
              k := k + 1
          end;

      { add remaining values from Feld2 to ErgebnisFeld}
      while j <= FELDLAENGE2 do
          begin
              ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
              j := j + 1;
              k := k + 1
          end;
```

Then you may use open arrays to make the routine more generic, so it could merge arrays of arbitrary lenghts, not just 5 plus 8.

You can also explicitly pass the lengths of both input lists as parameters to the routine, so it can merge lists *shorter* than arrays in which they're stored.

```
procedure mergeTwoArrays( var Feld1 : array of integer; feldLange1 : integer;
                          var Feld2 : array of integer; feldLange2 : integer;
                          var ErgebnisFeld : array of integer)
    var
        i, j, k : integer;
    begin
        i := 0;    { indices of open arrays start from 0 }
        j := 0;    { and end at length-1 }
        k := 0;

        { merge Feld1 and Feld2 to ErgebnisFeld until one of them becomes empty}
        while (i < feldLange1) and (j < feldLange2) do { note the comp. operator }
            if Feld1[i] <= Feld2[j] then
              begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
                i := i + 1;
                k := k + 1
              end
            else
              begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
                j := j + 1;
                k := k + 1
              end;

        { add remaining values from Feld1 to ErgebnisFeld}
        while i < feldLange1 do
            begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld1[i];
                i := i + 1;
                k := k + 1
            end;

        { add remaining values from Feld2 to ErgebnisFeld}
        while j < feldLange2 do
            begin
                ErgebnisFeld[k] := Feld2[j];
                j := j + 1;
                k := k + 1
            end;
    end;
```